# Error 3031 - not a valid password

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I am trying to access an MDB file via VB6 and receiving:

```
Error 3031 - not a valid password
```

What is the likely cause?  I believe I am sending the correct password of the file yet it produces this error.

Comment: better connect thru ODBC

Answer (score 2):

**CAUSE:**
When you manually set the database password to a password with fourteen characters (the limit), you cannot use that same password to programmatically open the database

**SOLUTION:**

**1:**
Do not select a password that is longer than 13 characters if you need to open the database programmatically.

**2:**
When you open the database programmatically, you need only include the first 13 characters of the database password.

To make the example in the "Steps to Reproduce Problem" section work, change the following line of code

```
Set db = ws.OpenDatabase _
("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Samples\Northwind.mdb", _
False, False, "MS Access;PWD=FourteenCharac")
```

to read as follows:

```
Set db = ws.OpenDatabase _
("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Samples\Northwind.mdb", _
False, False, "MS Access;PWD=FourteenChara")
```

NOTE: This will programmatically open the `Northwind.mdb` database even though the password is not correct.